# Set and get "Automatically adjust brightness as ambient light changes"

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mac-app-store

Is there a way to programmatically set and get the "Automatically adjust brightness as ambient light changes" system setting on OS X that will be accepted for the Mac App Store?

Comment: Guess you'll have to do it with AppleScript/AppleEvents...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggle "Illuminate keyboard" without using private APIs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402478/toggle-illuminate-keyboard-without-using-private-apis)