# Toggle "Illuminate keyboard" without using private APIs

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mac-app-store

Is there a way to turn on and off the "Illuminate keyboard" setting programmatically, without using private APIs?

I need to do it in a way that will be accepted by the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the ScriptingBridge framework; it works by sending Apple events. The System Preferences application exposes ScriptingBridge bindings so you can access it.

Here some starting points:

- [ScriptingBridge Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/AboutScriptingBridge/AboutScriptingBridge.html)
- [SBSystemPrefs Sample Application](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SBSystemPrefs/Introduction/Intro.html)

If you go with ScriptingBridge and want to submit your application the Mac App Store, then you have to request a temporary exception entitlement to allow your application to send Apple events; check the [Entitlement Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html) to learn more about it.